# Confusion about proving there is no finite measure on a countable set $X$ other than the trivial measure which assigns measure $0$ to every set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, definition, lebesgue-measure

A measure $\nu$ is finite if $\nu(X) < \infty$.

Let $X$ be a countable set and let $\mathcal A$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $X$. Prove there is no finite measure on $X$ other than the trivial measure which assigns measure $0$ to every set.

What if $X$ is finite? We can assign to each set in the $\sigma$-algebra, the cardinality of the set. So $\nu(X)=|X|$.

Comment: You need to put some restriction to ensure such a measure does not exist. For example there is no **translation invariant** finite measure on a countably-infinite set. Otherwise there are as many measures as there are convergent series.

Answer (score 5):

The claim is not true. Let $(x_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of $X$. Then let $\mu(\{x_k\}) = 2^{-k}$. This generates a finite measure on $X$ with $\mu(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} = 1$.

Comment: Why would $\mu(\{x_1\} )=1/2$ but $\mu(\{x_2\} )= 1/4$?

Comment: A measure can behave like that. You haven't said that $\mu$ should be symmetric in any way.

Comment: Oh, I am not sure. The question in the book is posed as such.

Comment: Does it matter at all that we are considering the sigma algebra consisting of the power set of $X$?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding why we are allowed to define $\mu$ in such a way. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: We're taking $\mathcal A$ to be the power set of  $X$. Therefore singleton sets (i.e. sets containing only one point) are measurable. And nothing forces every singleton set to have the same measure. For an arbitrary set $E \subseteq U$ we set $\mu(E) = \sum_{x \in E} \mu(\{x\})$. This satisfies all the axioms of a measure. Check it!

Comment: But wouldn't different enumerations of $X$ lead to different values for a subset?

Comment: Yes, it would. So what?

Comment: Then $\mu$ would not be well defined. Would it?

Comment: Yes it would. We take a specific enumeration. If you want a specific example, take $X=\mathbb N$ with its natural enumeration (and no other enumeration).